# Why are some variables attached to self in the "Specifying sparse partial derivatives for a simple vectorized component" video?

Tags: python, openmdao

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c4UJ-meHNY) video, Justin has written the following in the compute function of his component.

```
def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

    self.alp_sc = 0.91
    T0 = 28. #reference temperature
    eff0 = .285 #efficiency at ref temp
    T1 = -150.
    eff1 = 0.335

    delta_T = inputs['T'] - T0
    self.slope = (eff1 - eff0) / (T1 - T0)

    outputs['eta'] = (eff0 + self.slope * delta_T)/self.alp_sc
```

Why does he choose to use `self.slope` and `self.alp_sc` instead of just plain variables? Is it something important for openMDAO/vectorised components, or just an arbitrary choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the snippet of code it looks like `def compute(self, inputs, outputs)` is a method inside of an object/class. This can be seen from `self` being conatined in its initialisation.

`self.slope` and 'self.alp_sc`will be variables that are declared within the scope of the object that the`compute()` method is part of.

See [classes in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for more on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand classes and self in Python - my question was more about why exactly he chose to use self variables. I just spotted that he reuses the values in the compute_partials function :)

Answer (score 1):

The attributes (e.g. `self.alp_sc`) are constants that were never intended to change for that sample component.  They do not need to be input variables, because they will never be connected to.

[It is considered a best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432357/is-it-necessary-or-recommended-to-define-partials-w-r-t-fixed-parameters) to define partial derivatives for all outputs with respect to all inputs in any component. Therefore, by making these values attributes, we can respect the best practice and avoid declaring partials for things we know will never change.

Comment: I would argue with that a bit. Declaring an attribute outside __init__ (or in case of OpenMDAO initialize) is not totally best practice. And this way you reassign the (constant) value to it in each call of compute, instead of just getting the reference to the memory, what you would only need in this case.  For floats of course it won't make any noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you continue to watch the [video](https://youtu.be/7c4UJ-meHNY?t=497), `self.slope` and `self.alp_sc` are also used in the `compute_partials` method. `self.alp_sc` is constant, so I think it could have been declared in the `initialize` method of the class (if it is a parameter, that you want to potentially change for different instances), or outside of the class (if it is really a constant). `self.slope` in this case is also a constant, so the same applies. But imagine, the slope would depend on the input of your component, and you would need to recalculate it in each iteration (and let's say it is also very computationally expensive, which in the example is clearly not). In this case you could save some computations by storing the value in a class attribute (self.slope) and just reusing it in the derivative computation. 
One thing, that must to be ensured is, that in each iteration `compute` is called before `compute_partials` (otherwise you could end up using an obsolete value from the previous iteration in the derivative calculation), but I think that is always true in the current OpenMDAO 3.0.

It is quite common that you need to calculate the same quantities for the function and for the derivatives. Storing it in an attribute is one way to do it (less computation), or calling the same function within compute and compute_partials (twice as much computation, less memory) is another way.

Comment: 100% agree with onodip regarding the location of constants in the `__init__`. That was an oversight on my part. 

I disagree with saving values in the `compute` to be used in the `compute_partials`. It saves compute but can cause problems when using a NewtonSolver without solve-subsystems. `compute_jacobian` might get different inputs than `compute`. This corner case is specifically why we don't provide the `output` vector in the `compute_partials` method. 

I recommend recomputing your output values inside your `compute_partials`, and if the duplication bothers you use a helper function